# Get GPS location in UTM format in xamarin forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am building cross platform app using Xamarin Forms and using below plugin to get the GPS location :
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin

The issue is that the location is in degrees format (Latitude , Longitude). Is there anyway I can get the UTM format instead ?

Comment: I think you have to convert... using google I have found http://romansk.blogspot.it/2013/09/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to.html

Comment: That could be a solution . Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried Proj.Net but I don't think it's supported in XF.It throws error saying MT2002: Can not resolve reference

Comment: I think you should try to google and find a math formula ...

Comment: I checked how it can be done in math and it's complicated !

Comment: https://geoutility.codeplex.com/ try this. there are source code... maybe you can try to rebuild with xamarin.. good luck